# Triac dimensioning in practice

Tags: triac

I'm about to replace a relay with a discrete triac design. The load is a (resistive) heater element and power 1200W @ 240V (RMS current ~5A). I will use zero crossing detection and max switching frequency of 1Hz. Environment temperature < 50C. The triac is fired from an mcu via optocoupler.

I'm looking for advices to create a robust solution from a practical point of view and in particular from field experience.

1. What rating should the triac have for V and A.
2. Is it possible/advisable to avoid a heat sink?
3. Voltage surges are common in the region, how will that effect component selection?
4. Can a (fast) fuse be effective in protecting the triac from short circuit and power surge? If not, are there known working solutions for circuit protection.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Properly rated relays are magic devices. A TRIAC will dissipate substantial energy due to voltage drop when on. A relay won't. The TRIAC has two series junctions so dissipate about 1.2W/A or more. 
If you switch very frequently a TRIAC may be the best solution. If you SOMETIMES switch at 1 Hz but on average switch at a lower rate a relay may be the best solution. A 100,000 operation rated device switched at 1 Hz average lasts about 1 day. At 1,000,000 operation it lasts about 2 weeks. But an average of 1 operation per hour of a 100,000 operation device will give about a 10 year lifetime.

Comment: Thanks Russel. Yes, reason for the change was the limited life time of relays when switching frequency increases.

Comment: Yiu say load is pure resistive. If this is the case the following will not help as much but may still be useful. - With reactive loads One "trick" is to use a TRIC in parallel with relay contacts. Switch TRIAC on, then relay, then turn TRIAC off. TRIAC sees lower to much   lower dissipation depending on on/off times and relay has surge current removed. Better is probably a FET based bipolar switch (FET in bridge or 2 FETS) which entails more complexity but gives more flexible control of what happens when. ...

Comment: ... Having solid state switch handle turnoff is also liable to be a major contributor to lifetime improvement with reactive loads.

Comment: Thanks Russel, never thought of that. I'll take note of that and keep it for future projects!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As high as you can afford. 25A or 40A would be good. No triac you can afford will be as rugged (or efficient) as a relay contact.
2. Not a hope. Dissipation will be in the 5W range- read the datasheets and do some calculations. Do **not** run the triac junction too hot. It won't last long and you need the delta between operating temperature and absolute maximum to absorb the temperature surge from a short or other abuse.
3. Use at least a 600V triac, preferably 800V, and consider an MOV.
4. Yes, a fast fuse can protect a generously overrated triac from a short circuit. The more demands you place on the fuse, the more expensive and hard-to-find it becomes, and the more likely your customer will replace it with a penny or whatever.

Keep in mind that triacs are much more likely to fail 'on' than properly rated relays or contactors are.

Comment: Thanks Spehro. You confirmed my suspicions, in particular the risk of failing on, which is a headache.